# Backbone Drop Event Listener Amongst Two Views

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

My app has a dashboard with two panels.  Each panel is a different Backbone View that renders out a template within the respective panel.  The Views are instantiated by a Backbone Router.  I need to put a Drop Event Listener somewhere to detect when an `<li>` element from one View has been dropped onto the second View.  But, I don't know where to put this listener...

• I can't get the event to fire when I put the event in either of the views like `"drop #drop-zone":   "handleDrop"`

• Putting the Event Listener in the Router after the views are instantiated doesn't work either.

• My next thought would be to put the Drop Event Listener inside a Listener for dragStart, but I'm not sure if this is the best route to go.

Where is the appropriate place to listen for that Drop Event?

Answer (score 0):

```
// app.js, main.js, router.js, etc.
window.event_bus = {};

_.extend(object, Backbone.Events);

event_bus.on("drop", function(target) {
    // do something with target
});

// drop-zone-one-view.js
"drop #drop-zone-one": function () { event_bus.trigger('drop', 'drop-zone-one') }

// drop-zone-two-view.js
"drop #drop-zone-two": function () { event_bus.trigger('drop', 'drop-zone-two') }
```

Comment: Could you please add in some extra information as to where I would put this in my Backbone app?  Shoudl I split this up amongst the Views and the Router?

Comment: You've got it. I've updated my answer to be a little more specific.